Cannot instance custom environment with OpenAI Gymnasium
I'm trying to make my own checkers bot to try and teach myself reinforment learning.  I decided to try using Gymnasium as a framework and have been following the tutorials at https://gymnasium.farama.org/introduction/create_custom_env/.
For some reason, calling env = gym.make('CheckerWorld-v0') is causing the error
Exception has occurred: NameNotFound
Environment `CheckerWorld` doesn't exist.
  File "D:\dev\starling2\game\2024\checkers_ai\python\train_agent.py", line 17, in <module>
    env = gym.make('CheckerWorld-v0')
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
gymnasium.error.NameNotFound: Environment `CheckerWorld` doesn't exist.

I am adding my environment to the registry in my checkers_gym.py module:
class CheckerWorldEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, playing_as_black:bool = True, max_turns:int = 200):
        ...

gym.register(
    id="gymnasium_env/CheckerWorld-v0",
    entry_point=CheckerWorldEnv,
)

I am also importing the module with my environment with from checkers_gym import *
My custom environment is also listed in the registry as I can see with print(gym.envs.registry.keys())
dict_keys(['CartPole-v0', 'CartPole-v1', 'MountainCar-v0', 'MountainCarContinuous-v0', 'Pendulum-v1', 'Acrobot-v1', 'phys2d/CartPole-v0', 'phys2d/CartPole-v1', 'phys2d/Pendulum-v0', 'LunarLander-v3', 'LunarLanderContinuous-v3', 'BipedalWalker-v3', 'BipedalWalkerHardcore-v3', 'CarRacing-v3', 'Blackjack-v1', 'FrozenLake-v1', 'FrozenLake8x8-v1', 'CliffWalking-v0', 'Taxi-v3', 'tabular/Blackjack-v0', 'tabular/CliffWalking-v0', 'Reacher-v2', 'Reacher-v4', 'Reacher-v5', 'Pusher-v2', 'Pusher-v4', 'Pusher-v5', 'InvertedPendulum-v2', 'InvertedPendulum-v4', 'InvertedPendulum-v5', 'InvertedDoublePendulum-v2', 'InvertedDoublePendulum-v4', 'InvertedDoublePendulum-v5', 'HalfCheetah-v2', 'HalfCheetah-v3', 'HalfCheetah-v4', 'HalfCheetah-v5', 'Hopper-v2', 
'Hopper-v3', 'Hopper-v4', 'Hopper-v5', 'Swimmer-v2', 'Swimmer-v3', 'Swimmer-v4', 'Swimmer-v5', 'Walker2d-v2', 'Walker2d-v3', 'Walker2d-v4', 'Walker2d-v5', 'Ant-v2', 'Ant-v3', 'Ant-v4', 'Ant-v5', 'Humanoid-v2', 'Humanoid-v3', 'Humanoid-v4', 'Humanoid-v5', 'HumanoidStandup-v2', 'HumanoidStandup-v4', 'HumanoidStandup-v5', 'GymV21Environment-v0', 'GymV26Environment-v0', 'gymnasium_env/CheckerWorld-v0'])

I've also tried using env = gym.make('gymnasium_env/CheckerWorld-v0'), but I still get the same error.  How am I supposed to create a new instanced of my environment?
